# Android AccountManager alias for name

Tags: android, accountmanager

I'm using AccountAuthenticator and SyncAdapter in application, for accounts stored in AccountManager I use my own ACCOUN_TYPE and server specific identifier as ACCOUNT_NAME (Let's say "com.example.account_type" and "xxx-long-hashed-id" respectively).
I have to use this identity to keep that account distinct from another, because as far as I understand AccountManager uses both type and name to ensure account uniqueness.

The problem is, when I open system Settings->Account page for my app I see this ugly identifier as name, but I wanted put there username associated with this identity (I also see this in Contacts app - I export contacts there). If I started to use username as ACCOUNT_NAME, any time I change username in my app, I would see another account there, although it should be the same. Is there any way or workaround to use identity as name, but provide user-readable name to the system?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no alias mechanism for accounts in Android. Using the actual username is the intended way to create accounts. If you need to change the account name, you have to remove and re-add the account. For API level 21+ there is a method called [AccountManager.renameAccount(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#renameAccount%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.accounts.Account%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29) but it does essentially the same. It's up to your app to migrate any data from the old account to the new one, Android won't do that for you.

Regarding the uniqueness of accounts, it's sufficient if the account name is unique among all accounts of your account type. So given all users of your service have unique usernames, there is nothing to worry about.